# Missing inbox message

Tags: support, email, global-inbox

I received an email stating that there was a message in my inbox. By the time I read the email, that message was nowhere to be found. Any idea on where this message could be or what happened to it?[image]

Answer (score 5):

It says an answer was posted on July 23rd at 16:13. When I look at the [Genealogy homepage](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/), I can see it's *modified* at that time by a [1-reputation user with no contributions](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/14915/user14915):

[image]

That means their answer has been deleted (not necessarily in the same minute though), either by themselves or for reasons of moderation. The likelihood of that answer containing useful information for you is rather small, but I guess the Genealogy moderators would be able to dig it up.